# Unable to create thumbnail of "webp image" in PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am working on upload image and create thumb, Everything is working fine but whenever i trying to upload "webp image" then image is not uploading and i am getting following error
Your server does not support the GD function required to process this type of image
Here is my current code,Where i am wrong ?

```
$imagePrefix = time(); 
$imagename = "img_".$imagePrefix.trim($_FILES['file']['name']);
$config['upload_path'] = 'uploads/nft/'; 
$config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg|png|gif|PNG|JPG|JPEG|avif|webp'; 
$config['file_name'] = $imagename; 
$this->load->library('upload',$config); 
if($this->upload->do_upload('file'))
    { 
        $uploadData = $this->upload->data(); 
        $filename = $uploadData['file_name']; 
        $datas=$_POST;
        $data = $this->upload->data();
        $this->load->library('image_lib');
        $config2['image_library'] = 'gd2';
        $config2['source_image'] = $uploadData['full_path'];
        $config2['new_image'] = './uploads/nft/thumb/'.$uploadData["raw_name"].$uploadData['file_ext'];
        $config2['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
        $config2['maintain_ratio'] = FALSE;
        $config2['width'] = 350;
        $config2['height'] = 350;
        $this->image_lib->initialize($config2);
```

```
$this->image_lib->clear();
```

}

Comment: @MarkusZeller How ? i mean other image "thumbnail" created successfully but i am getting error only with "webp image"

Comment: What is unclear about _"Your server does not support the GD function required to process this type of image"_? The image library you are using there, can not process webp images.

Answer (score 0):

normal file upload method use to call another funcation to  createThumbnail() call

```
                $config['remove_spaces'] = TRUE;
                $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg|gif|png';
                $config['upload_path'] = './images/files';
                $config['remove_spaces'] = TRUE;
                $config['encrypt_name'] = TRUE;
                $this->load->library('upload', $config);
                if ($this->upload->do_upload('img')) {
                    $imgDetailsd = $this->upload->data();
                    $this->createThumbnail($imgDetailsd['file_name'], 200, 200, "./images/site/files", "your thumbnail file location save");
                }
```

try this thumb funcation create what you need image dimension

```
function createThumbnail($image_name,$new_width,$new_height,$uploadDir,$moveToDir)
{
$path = $uploadDir . '/' . $image_name;

$mime = getimagesize($path);

if($mime['mime']=='image/png') { 
    $src_img = imagecreatefrompng($path);
}
if($mime['mime']=='image/jpg' || $mime['mime']=='image/jpeg' || $mime['mime']=='image/pjpeg') {
    $src_img = imagecreatefromjpeg($path);
}   

$old_x          =   imageSX($src_img);
$old_y          =   imageSY($src_img);

$width = imagesx( $src_img );
$height = imagesy( $src_img );

if ($width > $height) {
    if($width < $new_width)
        $new_width = $width;
    
    else
    
    $new_width = $new_width;    
    
    
    $divisor = $width / $new_width;
    $new_height = floor( $height / $divisor);
}
else {
    
     if($height < $new_height)
         $new_height = $height;
     else
         $new_height =  $new_height;
     
    $divisor = $height / $new_height;
    $new_width = floor( $width / $divisor );
}

$dst_img        =   ImageCreateTrueColor($new_width,$new_height);

imagecopyresampled($dst_img,$src_img,0,0,0,0,$new_width,$new_height,$old_x,$old_y); 


// New save location
$new_thumb_loc = $moveToDir . $image_name;

if($mime['mime']=='image/png') {
    $result = imagepng($dst_img,$new_thumb_loc,8);
}
if($mime['mime']=='image/jpg' || $mime['mime']=='image/jpeg' || $mime['mime']=='image/pjpeg') {
    $result = imagejpeg($dst_img,$new_thumb_loc,80);
}

imagedestroy($dst_img); 
imagedestroy($src_img);

return $result;


}
```